# wxpython creataStatusBar strange behavior

Tags: python, wxpython

I have some wxpython code that behave strangely.. this is OKAY code:

```
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title,size=(500, 300))
        self.CreateStatusBar() 
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.srcSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        srcButton = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "src")
        srcButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onSrcButton)
        self.srcSizer.Add(srcButton, 0)
        self.srcTxt = wx.TextCtrl(panel, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.srcSizer.Add(self.srcTxt, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=10)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.srcSizer, 0 , flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.TOP, border=10)


        panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Show(True)
```

now when I swap the two lines of creating statusbar and the panel so they become

```
panel = wx.Panel(self)
self.CreateStatusBar()
```

Then the button and the textctrl are overlapped when the window is loaded, and they are brought back to normal position when resizing the window manually !!

Does self.CreatStatusBar() have always to be before creating panels or something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateStatusBar()` triggers a resize event on the frame to make room for the status bar. If the panel was already created, it is resized to fit the client
area of the frame. Resizing the panel triggers a resize event on the panel which will then recalulate its layout (the sizer) if applicable.

Creating controls (to be added to the panel's sizer) simply places them at the default position (0,0) with their default size. They will require
a layout (sizer) update to be moved to their correct position. (that's why there's a pile of controls at the upper left corner when the problem occurs.)

When the frame is shown, a resize event is fired (again). However, if the panel already fits the client area of the frame, the panel's resize event is not triggered,
therefore its layout is not updated.

You can observe that effect by creating the panel with the size of the client area even without the status bar:

```
panel = wx.Panel(self,size=self.GetClientSize())
#self.CreateStatusBar()
```

Likewise, you can trigger the update by setting the size of the panel to something else (once the frame is shown, it will resize the panel again):

```
# at the end of __init__
panel.SetSize(0,0)
```

However, this would create an unnecessary resize: first when you manually `SetSize()` and again in `frame.Show()`. There's a better way (shown below).

In `wx 2.8`, this issue applies to `CreateToolBar()` as well. `wx 2.9.4` appears to handle the toolbar correctly.

---

As a workaround, you can:

- create toolbar/statusbar *before* you create the panel **or** *after* you set the panel's sizer (that requires to add the controls to the sizer first)
- recalculate the panel's layout after you set the sizer:

  ```
  panel.SetSizer(sizer)
  panel.Layout()
  ```